# MVC5 Autocomplete - Error

Tags: exception, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-5

I have default mvc5 project. When I want to do autocomplete textbox it doesn't recognize autocomplete function.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did I fix this?

- Use jQuery UI: Although I had the scripts specified in a bundle called jqueryui, they’re not rendered. So I added this line under the jQuery bundle rendering in _Layout.cshtml:
- @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
  Render the jQuery UI CSS: jQuery UI requires some CSS files to be included. They were bundled, but not rendered; so I rendered them by adding @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") to my layout.